# Is there diffrence in 2>&1 vs 2>>&1?

Tags: linux, unix

Is there difference in `2>&1` and`2>>&1` in Linux?

I know about > and >>.
Also know about 1,2,3 mean standard output/error/input.

Comment: Best way to find out is simply try it and you'll see that appending does not even work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a syntax error in bash.

```
$ echo hello 2>>&1
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'`
```

`>>` only works with a real file path

```
$ echo hello 1>>/tmp/xx
```